Text Based Game Warning Messages in PyCharm
I am doing a text based game for a school project. I finished my code, and things are running smoothly. However, in PyCharm, I get the following warnings:
Line 101: Local variable 'direction' might be referenced before assignment.
Line 111: Local variable 'item' might be referenced before assignment.
Line 105 & 124: Too broad exception clause
I can't figure out how to fix these warnings. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!
# Name Here

# Function showing goal of the game and move commands
def show_instructions():
    # Display main menu and the commands
    print('The Serial Killer Cadet')
    print('------------------------------')
    print('You are an officer at a police academy who is determined to apprehend a cadet'
          ' who has turned out to be a dangerous serial killer.')
    print('Collect 6 crucial items before confronting the serial killer to win the game or be killed!')
    print('------------------------------')
    print('Move directions: go North, go East, go South, go West')
    print('Add item to inventory: get [item name]')
    print('Quit Game: "Exit"')
    print('------------------------------')


# Calls the instruction function
show_instructions()


# Function showing player's status
def show_status(current_room, inventory):
    # Display player's current room, inventory
    print(f'You are in the {current_room}\nInventory: {inventory}')


# Dictionary linking rooms and items
def main():
    rooms = {
        'Training Field': {'North': 'Weapon Room', 'East': 'Uniform Room', 'South': 'Locker Room', 'West': 'Kennel'},
        'Weapon Room': {'East': 'Office', 'South': 'Training Field', 'Item': 'Baton'},
        'Office': {'West': 'Weapon Room', 'Item': 'Handcuffs'},
        'Uniform Room': {'North': 'Barracks', 'West': 'Training Field', 'Item': 'Ballistic Vest'},
        'Barracks': {'South': 'Uniform Room', 'Item': 'Flashlight'},
        'Kennel': {'East': 'Training Field', 'Item': 'K9'},
        'Locker Room': {'North': 'Training Field', 'East': 'Basement', 'Item': 'Taser'},
        'Basement': {'West': 'Locker Room', 'Villain': 'Serial Killer'}  # Villain
    }

    # Player will initially be placed in the Training Field
    current_room = 'Training Field'

    # Create inventory
    inventory = []

    # Gameplay loop
    while True:
        # Display player info
        show_status(current_room, inventory)

        # Item indicator
        if 'Item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            nearby_item = rooms[current_room]['Item']

            if nearby_item not in inventory:
                # Plural item
                if nearby_item[-1] == 's':
                    print(f'You see {nearby_item}.')

                # Singular item
                else:
                    print(f'You see a {nearby_item}.')

        print('------------------------------')

        # Villain encounter
        if 'Villain' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            # Lose condition
            if len(inventory) < 6:
                print(
                    'You were killed by the serial killer...GAME OVER!\n'
                    'Thank you for playing the game. Hope you enjoyed it (:')
                break
            # Win condition
            else:
                print(
                    'Congratulations! You have captured the serial killer cadet!\nThank you for playing the game. Hope'
                    'you enjoyed it (:')
                break

        # Player's move input
        user_input = input('Enter your move:\n')

        # Split move into words
        next_move = user_input.split(' ')

        # First word is an action
        action = next_move[0].title()

        if len(next_move) > 1:
            item = next_move[1:]
            direction = next_move[1].title()

            item = ' '.join(item).title()

        # Moving between rooms
        if action == 'Go':
            # Valid direction
            try:
                current_room = rooms[current_room][direction] # Line 101
                print(f'You travel {direction}.')

            # Invalid direction
            except Exception: # Line 105
                print("You can't go that way!")

        # Getting item
        elif action == 'Get':
            try:
                if item == rooms[current_room]['Item']: # Line 111
                    if item not in inventory:
                        inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['Item'])
                        print(f'{item} retrieved!')

                    # Item already in inventory
                    else:
                        print(f'You already have the {item}.')

                # Invalid item for room
                else:
                    print(f"Can't find {item}.")

            except Exception: # Line 124
                print(f"Can't find {item}.")

        # Quit game
        elif action == 'Exit':
            break

        # Any other commands
        else:
            print('Invalid command')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


It ran successfully in pycharm, however it seems like the IDE you're using complaining about variable might be referenced before assignment. I just create the direction variable in line 48 but rest of the code is same -
# Name Here

# Function showing goal of the game and move commands
def show_instructions():
    # Display main menu and the commands
    print('The Serial Killer Cadet')
    print('------------------------------')
    print('You are an officer at a police academy who is determined to apprehend a cadet'
          ' who has turned out to be a dangerous serial killer.')
    print('Collect 6 crucial items before confronting the serial killer to win the game or be killed!')
    print('------------------------------')
    print('Move directions: go North, go East, go South, go West')
    print('Add item to inventory: get [item name]')
    print('Quit Game: "Exit"')
    print('------------------------------')


# Calls the instruction function
show_instructions()


# Function showing player's status
def show_status(current_room, inventory):
    # Display player's current room, inventory
    print(f'You are in the {current_room}\nInventory: {inventory}')


# Dictionary linking rooms and items
def main():
    rooms = {
        'Training Field': {'North': 'Weapon Room', 'East': 'Uniform Room', 'South': 'Locker Room', 'West': 'Kennel'},
        'Weapon Room': {'East': 'Office', 'South': 'Training Field', 'Item': 'Baton'},
        'Office': {'West': 'Weapon Room', 'Item': 'Handcuffs'},
        'Uniform Room': {'North': 'Barracks', 'West': 'Training Field', 'Item': 'Ballistic Vest'},
        'Barracks': {'South': 'Uniform Room', 'Item': 'Flashlight'},
        'Kennel': {'East': 'Training Field', 'Item': 'K9'},
        'Locker Room': {'North': 'Training Field', 'East': 'Basement', 'Item': 'Taser'},
        'Basement': {'West': 'Locker Room', 'Villain': 'Serial Killer'}  # Villain
    }

    # Player will initially be placed in the Training Field
    current_room = 'Training Field'

    # Create inventory
    inventory = []

    # Initialize direction
    direction = ""

    # Gameplay loop
    while True:
        # Display player info
        show_status(current_room, inventory)

        # Item indicator
        if 'Item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            nearby_item = rooms[current_room]['Item']

            if nearby_item not in inventory:
                # Plural item
                if nearby_item[-1] == 's':
                    print(f'You see {nearby_item}.')

                # Singular item
                else:
                    print(f'You see a {nearby_item}.')

        print('------------------------------')

        # Villain encounter
        if 'Villain' in rooms[current_room].keys():
            # Lose condition
            if len(inventory) < 6:
                print(
                    'You were killed by the serial killer...GAME OVER!\n'
                    'Thank you for playing the game. Hope you enjoyed it (:')
                break
            # Win condition
            else:
                print(
                    'Congratulations! You have captured the serial killer cadet!\nThank you for playing the game. Hope'
                    'you enjoyed it (:')
                break

        # Player's move input
        user_input = input('Enter your move:\n')

        # Split move into words
        next_move = user_input.split(' ')

        # First word is an action
        action = next_move[0].title()

        if len(next_move) > 1:
            item = next_move[1:]
            direction = next_move[1].title()

            item = ' '.join(item).title()

        # Moving between rooms
        if action == 'Go':
            # Valid direction
            try:
                current_room = rooms[current_room][direction] # Line 101
                print(f'You travel {direction}.')

            # Invalid direction
            except Exception: # Line 105
                print("You can't go that way!")

        # Getting item
        elif action == 'Get':
            try:
                if item == rooms[current_room]['Item']: # Line 111
                    if item not in inventory:
                        inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['Item'])
                        print(f'{item} retrieved!')

                    # Item already in inventory
                    else:
                        print(f'You already have the {item}.')

                # Invalid item for room
                else:
                    print(f"Can't find {item}.")

            except Exception: # Line 124
                print(f"Can't find {item}.")

        # Quit game
        elif action == 'Exit':
            break

        # Any other commands
        else:
            print('Invalid command')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

